# 'git lfs fetch' found 1 object, what does it mean?

Tags: github, git-lfs

In order to backup some GitHub repositories, I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository), cloned those repositories with the `--mirror` option and then fetched Git LFS. Sometimes the output is simple:

```
$ git lfs fetch --all
fetch: Fetching all references...
```

However, for some repositories, the output would be:

```
$ git lfs fetch --all
fetch: 1 object found, done.
fetch: Fetching all references...
```

Both would create an empty folder `lfs/tmp` without downloading anything. So what does "1 object found" mean? Why is there a difference between repositories?

Git LFS doc didn't explain the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/discussions/5123) by bk2204 (Git LFS maintainer):

> Hey,
>
> In order to find how many objects need to be fetched, Git LFS walks the history. "1 object found" means that it walked the history and found a single LFS pointer file. The reason you're probably seeing this message is that an empty file is its own pointer, and thus it will report a single object if you have an empty file in your repository. However, it won't actually download anything because it doesn't need to in that case.